# ¿Como muestro o no muestro algo dependiendo del tipo de usuario en Laravel?

Tags: laravel

En mi código hay 3 tipos de usuarios:

[image: imagen de la base de datos]

usuario tipo 1, tipo 2 y tipo 3

¿Cómo hacer (Por ejemplo) que un botón solo se muestre a un usuario tipo 2?

botón de ejemplo:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="parent-link">@lang('My Log')</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-lists">

        <li><a href="{{route('transaction')}}">@lang('Transaction Log')</a></li>
        <li><a href="{{route('depositLog')}}">@lang('Payment Log')</a></li>
        @if($basic->withdraw_status == 1)
        <li><a href="{{route('user.withdraw-log')}}">@lang('Withdraw Log')</a></li>
        @endif
    </ul>
</li>
```

Botón para seleccionar el tipo de usuario cuando te registras:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="last_name" class="font-weight-bold text-white">@lang('User type')</label>
        <select type="text" name="user_type" >
          <option value="">Select your user type</option>
            @foreach($plans as $plan)
                <option value="{{$plan->id}}">{{$plan->name}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>

        @if ($errors->has('user_type'))
            <span class="text-danger">{{ $errors->first('user_type') }}</span>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @BetaM No soy un experto en Laravel, me gusta modificar cosas, por ejemplo te explico como en el registro de usuarios cuando el usuario puede escoger su tipo de usuario:  `<select type="text" name="user_type" >
                                          <option value="">Select your user type</option>
                                            @foreach($plans as $plan)
                                                <option value="{{$plan->id}}">{{$plan->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                           </select>`

Comment: @BetaM no puedo usar: Auth::user()->user_type, o si? solo quiero que un determinado bloque de HTML no se muestre y ya, o si, depende del tipo de usuario

Comment: Creo que no me explique para nada bien, solo necesito que un bloque se muestre o no dependiendo del tipo de usuario, perdona!, Soy nuevo aqui :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En la plantilla de blade

```
<button> Aceptar </button>
@if (Auth::user()->user_type == 2) 
<button> Boton para usuarios tipo 2</button>
@endif
<button> Cancelar </button>
```

Comment: @BetaM yo estoy contestando a la pregunta "¿Como hacer (Por ejemplo) que un boton solo se muestre a un usuario tipo 2?"

Comment: Lo que te está explicando es como hace el registro del usuario, cuando pone usuario contraseña y correo tiene un combo para seleccionar el tipo de usuario... y después dependiendo de lo que haya escogido el usuario quiere mostrar un botón que es la pregunta y es mi respuesta :)

Comment: @j0se ESTO ME AYUDO DEMASIDO (Tengo que seguir estudiando)

Comment: @j0se y si quiero que una pagina entera la vea solo un tipo de usuario?

Comment: @jesuscurreri si te ayudó lo suyo es que marques la respuesta como correcta ;) y bienvenido

Comment: @jesuscurreri eso último que mencionas lo manejas mejor desde el controlador ahi filtras y redireccionas según el usuario y su tipo

Comment: Como bien te dice @BetaM lo suyo es que en el controlador donde renderizas la vista pues si es un tipo de usuario renderices una vista y si no es ese usuario renderices otra

Comment: @j0se Gracias, listo!

Comment: Una vez aclarados los puntos y que el OP se explicó mejor te doy mi  +1 @j0se

Answer (score 0):

debes preguntar por el usuario, tal cual ha dicho el comentario de arriba.

usando

```
Auth::user()->user_type
```

puedes acceder a la propiedad user_type y ya trabajar con eso, preguntando si es 1 2 o el que necesites